# In Django, how can I specify that a CharField of max_length 5 should only accept numbers (i.e. zipcode) in the model?

Tags: django-models

How can I specify that a CharField of max_length 5 can only accept numerical characters (i.e. zipcode) in the model?  Is this the best way to store a zipcode?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's [`localflavor`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/) add-on defines model fields for various geographical constructs, including [zipcodes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USZipCodeField).

Comment: Since you seem to know about this stuff -- is there also a quick add on that can validate email addresses?